# Why I cannot Archive project that contains App Clip while using Cocoapods?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, apple-appclips

I am facing an issue integrating an App Clip into an existing project.

The project uses Cocoapods and after spending quite some time to adding relevant files to the target, modifying the Podfile, etc. When attempting to archive the iOS target that contains the App Clip I get the following error:

[image]

The issue seems to be related to the Firebase InAppMessaging pod.

Here is the Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '12.4'
inhibit_all_warnings!


workspace 'SomeWorkspace'
project './SomeProject.xcodeproj'

def shared_pods

  use_frameworks!

  # Firebase UI
  pod 'FirebaseUI/Database'
  pod 'FirebaseUI/Auth'
  pod 'FirebaseUI/Google'
  pod 'FirebaseUI/Facebook'

  # Firebase
  pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
  pod 'Firebase/InAppMessaging'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'Firebase/Functions'
  pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'
  pod 'CodableFirebase'

  # Apollo iOS
  pod 'Apollo', '0.31.0'

  # Apps Flyer
  pod 'AppsFlyerFramework'

  # Facebook
  pod 'FacebookCore'

  # Segment
  pod "Analytics", "3.7.0"

  # Crashlytics
  pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.9.0'

  pod 'GoogleMaps', '~> 3.8.0'
  pod 'Intercom'
  pod 'SwiftyBeaver'
  pod 'Swinject'
  pod 'Stripe', '19.0.1'

  pod 'RxSwift'
  pod 'RxDataSources', '~> 4.0.0'
  pod 'RxViewController'
  pod 'RxGesture'
  pod 'RxCoreLocation', '~> 1.4'

  pod 'SnapKit', '~> 5.0.0'

  # Reachability
  pod 'RxReachability'

  pod 'RxSwiftExt', '~> 5'
  pod 'RxKeyboard'
  pod 'RxFirebase/Database'

  #Algolia
  pod 'InstantSearch', '~> 5.0'

  #User interface
  pod 'SwiftMessages'

end

target 'ClientDev' do
    shared_pods
end

target 'ClientProd' do
    shared_pods
end

target 'ClientStaging' do
    shared_pods
end

target 'ClientClipDev' do

  use_modular_headers!

  # Firebase
  pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
  pod 'Firebase/InAppMessaging'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'Firebase/Functions'
  pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
  pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'
  pod 'CodableFirebase'

  # Google Maps
  pod 'GoogleMaps', '~> 3.8.0'

  # Apollo iOS
  pod 'Apollo', '0.31.0'

  # RxSwift
  pod 'RxSwift'
  pod 'RxDataSources', '~> 4.0.0'
  pod 'RxViewController'
  pod 'RxGesture'
  pod 'RxCoreLocation', '~> 1.4'
  pod 'RxSwiftExt', '~> 5'
  pod 'RxKeyboard'
  pod 'RxFirebase/Database'

  pod 'SnapKit', '~> 5.0.0'
  pod 'Swinject'
end
```

The iOS main app target's Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content

[image]

The App Clip app target's Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content

[image]

I know that Firebase doesn't currently work with App Clips and also that embedding Google Maps is a bad idea but those are things that I'm currently working on so are a non issue. The only issue is that for the life in me I'm unable to figure out how to get this project to Archive.

Of course, the project wsa cleaned, Derived Data was removed etc. So the issue is most likely related to the App Clip + Cocoapods.

Thanks in advance for your answers!

L.E.

It seems that there are 2 Bundles of FirebaseInAppMessaging generated but I cannot figure out why.

[image]

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? I am facing the same issue. The use_frameworks approach does not resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

In AppClip target, don't include

```sh
use_frameworks!
```

just comment it.

```sh
# use_frameworks!
```

or

---